# Creating a grid of coloured points

Tags: p-adic-number-theory, mathematica

I wish to create a grid of $31\times31$ points with coordinates of the form $(\frac k{30};\frac n{30})$ within the unit square, and give each point a colour based on the 2-adic value of both its coordinates.

I plan to use Wolfram Mathematica, as this program has a simple function to calculate the 2-adic value, but I do not know how to generate a grid in which I can assign colours to the points. If we write $v(x)$ as the 2-adic value of $x$, the colouring should be as follows:

$(x,y)$ is coloured:

- Blue if $v(x) \geq v(y)$ and $v(x) \geq v(1)=1$
- Green if $v(x) < v(y)$ and $v(y) \geq v(1)=1$
- Red if $v(x) < v(1)=1 $ and $ v(y) < v(1)=1$

Can someone help me?

Comment: I think you should ask here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/

Comment: When you say "2-adic value" do you mean the 2-adic norm or something else?

Comment: Yes, the 2-adic norm, in the proof I'm reading it's called the 2-adic value

Comment: GraphicsGrid[
 Table[Table[Graphics[{fun[i, j], Rectangle[]}], {i, 0, 30}], {j, 0, 
   30}]], where fun[i, j] returns the colour: Red, Green or Blue. p-adic norm can be found here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/p-adicNorm.html

Comment: My question has been solved here http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/95554/creating-a-grid-of-coloured-points